# Need help on my alarm program

Tags: c#

I want to make an alarm program where the user is asked to choose the time and the day of the week. If the user choose the day, the text in the label will be in bold. I am having trouble to pass the list from button2_click to Timer_Elapsed. The program worked well except when i pressed the button, the functions in Timer_Elapsed wont work.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime userTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    foreach(string _list in list)
    {
        if(currentTime.DayOfWeek.Equals(_list) && currentTime.Hour==userTime.Hour && currentTime.Minute==userTime.Minute && currentTime.Second == userTime.Second)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\Andrew\Music\test1.wav";
            player.PlayLooping();
            if(MessageBox.Show("","It's Time!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                player.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
    if (label3.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Monday");
    }
    if (label4.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Tuesday");
    }
    if (label5.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Wednesday");
    }
    if (label6.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Thursday");
    }
    if (label7.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Friday");
    }
    if (label8.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Saturday");
    }
    if (label9.Font.Bold)
    {
        list.Add("Sunday");
    }

    foreach (string _list in list)
    {
        label10.Text = label10.Text + _list + " ";
    }
    label10.Visible = true;
}

private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Font = new Font(label3.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Font = new Font(label4.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Font = new Font(label5.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label6.Font = new Font(label6.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label7.Font = new Font(label7.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label8.Font = new Font(label8.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label9.Font = new Font(label9.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Font = new Font(label3.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label4.Font = new Font(label4.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label5.Font = new Font(label5.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label6.Font = new Font(label6.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label7.Font = new Font(label7.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label8.Font = new Font(label8.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    label9.Font = new Font(label9.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In if statement, You are comparing `DayOfWeek` Enum value to string: `currentTime.DayOfWeek.Equals(_list)` this will be always false. Change with this:
`currentTime.DayOfWeek.ToString().Equals(_list)`

Comment: If used `ToStrin()` , why would he need to use `Equals` anyway ??? a simple `==` will do XD

Answer (score 0):

Just like Giorgi said, you are comparing the Enum to a string. You would need to ToString() it before.

As for the rest of your code, here are a couple pointers to make it better overall, since you seem to be beginning. If you don't understand one of the tips, try to read about it. Understanding why it is better is much more important than just blindly changing it. Most of the tips are extremely simplified pointers, and the level is pretty basic too.

### Better functionality:

- Make a label click either turn it bold or turn it back to normal, depending on it's current state. This will allow a user to remove one of them easily. This will make button1 irrelevant too.

  ```
  label3.Font = new Font(label3.Font, label3.Font.Bold ? FontStyle.Regular : FontStyle.Bold);
  ```
- Allow button2 to deactivate the alarm, by clicking it again.
- Do not hard-code the path to your sound, instead include it as a ressource, or just put it in the folder with the executable and use a relative path
- Nobody needs an alarm up to the second. Make the timer Interval about 30 seconds or so (to avoid millisecond errors), and compare up to the minute.
- Don't start the alarm if it is already ringing
- Safeguard your dangerous code, like finding the sound file, either by checking it exists beforehand (and reacting appropriately) or with a simple try catch, so that your program doesn't crash at critical moments.

### Better code:

- Add Enum values (from DayofWeek) to your list, then you will not need to convert anything to compare them
- Name your form controls and variables better, so that their use is obvious from the name. "label3", "button2", "list" are horrible names for variables, especially global ones.
- Considering the fact that you don't give any other option than "OK" when it rings, don't test the dialog response at all.

  ```
  player.PlayLooping();
  MessageBox.Show("", "It's time!");
  player.Stop();
  ```
- Use the same function for all label clicks, like this:

  ```
  private void labelDay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Label currentLbl = (label) sender;
      currentLbl.Font = new Font(currentLbl.Font, currentLbl.Font.Bold ? FontStyle.Regular : FontStyle.Bold);
  }
  ```
- Hold all your labels in an array, so that you can loop through them in the button clicks
- Compare the time using a difference, so that you don't have to compare days, then hours, then minutes, etc. A DateTime can easily be compared in one operation.
- WinForms has a timer component that you can use from the editor
- Dispose of your SoundPlayer when you're done with it, or re-use it. C# takes care of that for you behind the scenes, but that is a very good habit to learn in programming in general

That should be a good start to learning a few very useful things about C# and WinForms, and starting to use better code practices. This is in no way an exhaustive list of everything that could be improved, but since you probably don't plan on ever turning this program into a piece of software used by the whole world, this should be a good stepping stone for you.